# near-English identifiers -- what exactly are those?

Tags: meaning

Source: [The ABCs of IP Addressing by Gilbert Held (2002)](https://books.google.com/books/about/The_ABCs_of_IP_Addressing.html?id=Z4Dc0CpC8mcC&redir_esc=y)

Example:

> Most readers should be familiar with the entry of **near-English identifiers**, more formally referred to as Uniform Resource Locators (URLs), into a browser to access a particular Web page.

What exactly do they mean by that?

Comment: It means "names that are similar to English". But this just reveals the author's ignorance -- none of magyarhirlap.hu, asahi.com, aljazeera.com, arusharaha.com etc. etc. is "near-English". Do not use this term!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I read that as *almost English* but it could be *almost any language*.

Without these *almost lanugage identifiers*, we'd have to type http://74.125.21.113 to visit Google.

I'd never heard the term before this question though, so I wouldn't think it very widespread.

The clue is in the context, where it says

> more formally referred to as Uniform Resource Locators (URLs)

a URL looks like this:

```
http://ell.stackexchange.com/a/110494
```

Comment: I'm seconding the "I've never heard the term before" sentiment -- neither I, not any of the people I talk with regularly, have heard of it before -- and adding that you probably shouldn't use it. "URL" is basically universally recognized, so there's no point in trying to use another phrase that isn't anywhere near as common.

Comment: I suspect the author was trying to say something like "the entry of identifiers which are similar to a natural language such as English," not to invent a new technical term for "URL".